# Linux server status API over Http

Tags: linux, performance, http, server, monitoring

Is there any free tools that send Linux server status (like CPU/Ram usage, open ports, running services... etc) over Http? something like "call some rest with postman/curl from client and the server send back its status as a json".

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: when i said "API" its obviously about programing, and developing something,, if you don't know the answer,  you don't have to write something and voting down,,, im really sorry for stackoverflow for letting people like you voting or writing comment....

Answer (score 0):

Have you take a look on nagios?
It's open source and surely a good solution.

https://www.nagios.org/